# AOSP build both x86 and x64 for aosp_x86_64-eng

Tags: android-source

When building Android 9.0.0_r30, I lunch "aosp_x86_64-eng", but it builts both x86 and x64 targets, i.e. there are two clang invokes for each C/C++ source in the build log:

```
...clang...-target i686-linux-android...
...clang...-target x86_64-linux-android...
```

which generates two sets of binaries which wastes time and disk space.

Can I/how to only build x64 target?

Comment: This is not a mistake. All 64-bit Android systems must still support 32-bit apps.

Comment: @ Alex Cohn You are right, there is /system/lib and /system/lib64, but how can we build a custom Android that only supports x64?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably not have success with building an x64 Android without any x86 binaries. Every module can decide to be built in the target architecture, a fixed one or both and a lot of modules do that.

If you start to grep for `LOCAL_MULTILIB` in `Android.mk` and `compile_multilib` in `Android.bp`, you will find lots of modules and have to figure out the reason for every one of them to build for x86, x64 or both.

```sh
grep -rn "compile_multilib" --include="Android.bp"
grep -rn "LOCAL_MULTILIB" --include="Android.mk"
```

You can find out what the configurations mean here: https://source.android.com/setup/develop/64-bit-builds